# Android facebook PhotoShareDialogBuilder error

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to use PhotoShareDialogBuilder to upload photos to facebook and I'm getting an error from the facebook app when uploading is finished (The upload progress bar reaches 100% just before it errors).

The error message is:

> "Your photo could not be uploaded."
>
> "We're sorry, this upload can't be completed."

Steps I've taken to set the app up as per the documentation:

- Adding the facebook application to my solution
- Setting up the application on https://developers.facebook.com/
- Creating the app key/secret and dev hashkey and adding the app key to the application
- Adding a com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider to the androidmaniest.xml with the app key correctly attached
- Adding a UiLifecycleHelper and overriding all the activity functions
- Adding the following code to share the image in question:

  ```
  if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(context, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.PHOTOS) && FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(context, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
      //If you can find the facebook app, link to it
      FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder(getActivity())
              .addPhotos(Arrays.asList(renderedImage))
              .build();
      uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
  }
  ```

The "renderedImage" is a bitmap array with size of 1, as addPhotos must be passed a collection instead of a single image.

Extra info:

- I have used ShareDialogueBuilder to sucessfully post a text status to my facebook account, and link to a website, it's only uploading photos that is broken
- I tried multiple different sizes of image, and uploaded one of them to facebook manually from the phone to be sure it worked
- On the upload dialogue on the facebook app, the image preview displays correctly
- First stackexchange post, hope my formatting is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting this problem check your dev hash key

I'd previously got sharing links working but in between switching to pictures the hash key got overwritten or corrupted, and was causing my problems

If you're unsure, try just sharing a link, as the photo uploader does not tell you about the hash key error!